# Flash - Add frame to timeline, at start of timeline

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, timeline

There must be an easier way to add frames at the start of a flash timeline?

I want to insert a few frames before frame one, but I can not find a simple way to do so in Flash CS5.

- I have tried to use insert, it will place them to the right (frame
  2..).
- I have tried to drag all the frames of the movie over to the
  right, but it creates strange problems with the tweens (some even go away).

The only way I have found to do it, is create a new movie, insert frames, and then copy/paste the entire movie from the original flash in to this flash, is there a better way?

Comment: I would go for your second solution... the side effect is quite strange. Are you sure all your layers are editable when you select/drag the frames?

Comment: I think I would probably take your first approach. If you need 10 frames, insert 10 frames (F5 makes it easy to do quickly). When you've got the right number of frames, click the first frame. Then drag your keyframe to the frame where you want it. This will get you your frames at the beginning you're looking for and maintain your tweens.

Comment: That was a good hint - it may be that some of the layers were locked when I tried it, since it is not happening now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select multiple frames using <kbd>shift</kbd> and then **drag** them across. Empty frames will be inserted to fill the previously used up space.

See below:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

As for losing your tweens using this approach (if this is what you were doing) - just be sure that you've selected *all* of the frames in your timeline before doing this.